# Azure ARM template resourceId problem with nested deployments on subscription level

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm working on an ARM template to

A. deploy a resource group
B. deploy an ASE env.

To do both, as I understand I need to run a deployment on scope subscription level
`New-AzDeployment -Name TestingASE -TemplateFile $HOME/azuredeploy.json -TemplateParameterFile $HOME/parameters.json  -Location 'West Europe'`

My template is pretty long already - so here are the most important parts (I think).

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.1",
    "parameters": {
....
```

```
"resources": [
        // Resource Group
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "name": "storageDeployment",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/', parameters('rgName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
....
```

```
{
                            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
                            "name": "[parameters('asevnetname')]",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "addressSpace": {
                                    "addressPrefixes": [
                                        "[parameters('addressPrefix')]"
                                    ]
                                },
                                "subnets": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "[parameters('subnetName')]",
...
```

```
{
                            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
                            "type": "Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments",
                            "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                            "kind": "ASEV2",
                            "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "[parameters('aseName')]",
                                "location": "[parameters('Location')]",
                                "InternalLoadBalancingMode": "[parameters('ilbMode')]",
                                "virtualNetwork": {
                                    "Id": "[resourceId(subscription().id, resourceGroup().Id, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('asevnetname'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
                                }
....
```

This give me an output "The template function 'RESOURCEGROUP' is not expected at thislocation"
As far as I understand I'm following the guidelines
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourcegroup

> The resourceGroup() function can't be used in a template that is deployed at the subscription level. It can only be used in templates that are deployed to a resource group. You can use the resourceGroup() function in a linked or nested template (with inner scope) that targets a resource group, even when the parent template is deployed to the subscription. In that scenario, the linked or nested template is deployed at the resource group level.

Thanks for helping with this.

Answer (score 1):

The error happened at the [resourceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#resourceid) format, it should be

```
resourceId([subscriptionId], [resourceGroupName], resourceType, resourceName1, [resourceName2], ...)
```

> To get the resource ID for a resource in the same subscription but a
>   different resource group, provide the resource group name.
>
> ```
> "[resourceId('otherResourceGroup', 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'examplestorage')]"
> ```

So, in this case, the `virtualNetwork` ID in the properties of `Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments` should be

```
"virtualNetwork": {
 "Id": "[resourceId(parameters('rgName'), 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('asevnetname'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
}
```

or

```
"Id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('asevnetname'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
```

For more information, you could get more references to deploy an ASE within a subnet from [this template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/0d546fea32c65a1510a2c14e8eea1d76d347aed7/201-web-app-asev2-ilb-create/azuredeploy.json#L67).

Answer (score 0):

Your deployment schema is `subscriptionDeploymentTemplate` and the `New-AzDeployment` cmdlet creates a deployment at the subscription scope.  As per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#remarks-3) you can't use that function when deploying at the subscription scope.  You'll also encounter problems with the resourceId() function that wraps around it.  The subscriptionResourceId() function should solve your problem.

```
"virtualNetwork": {
    "Id": "[subscriptionResourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets',parameters('asevnetname'),parameters('subnetName'))]"
}
```

The resource id will be returned in the subscription format as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-resource#return-value-5), if that isn't an acceptable format for the `virtualNetwork.Id` property of the `Microsoft.Web/hostingEnvironments` resource you're trying to deploy you might need to construct the resource id using the `concat()` function instead.